# to_excel showed "No Excel writer 'openpyxl'"

Tags: pandas, openpyxl

I was trying to save a DataFrame data to Excel. Here is what I used
(df is the data and it contains 82 rows x 7 columns)

```
df.to_excel('output_test.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

but the output gave me this:

> No Excel writer 'openpyxl'

I have installed openpyxl and it can be imported. Could someone help me solve this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have the exact same problem; did you find a solution?

Comment: What version of openpyxl do you have?

Comment: openpyxl version 1.8.6 is installed and I am receiving the same error.